# Magento 2.4 Customer Login - Refresh page

Tags: magento2, customer-account, cookie, customer-session

I'm running into an issue on a Magento 2.4 website with 2 websites ( the one is on a seperate subdomain ).
Some customers cant login using their credentials, the page just reloads without any errors.

Deleting the PHPSESSID cookie of the one domain ( not the one their trying to login ) seems to works, but i dont understand why this is happening.

Is there a way to avoid this issue ? maybe somehow make magento store cookies "globaly" like *.domain.com ?

*UPDATE
The problem IS the two cookies, deleting either one makes the login pass, i think there is something happening with the domain path
1).site.com
2).subdomain.site.com

Is this a valid pattern for multi website Magento sites?

Comment: Maybe the form_key is incorrect. Have you checked the log? (`var/log` folder)

Comment: Invalid Form keys produces an error as far i am aware. And no, didn't notice any errors in the logs

Comment: One trick to debug is open the Network tab in devtools (chrome/firefox) and then check the keep/preserve log, when you are redirect, check if the previous requests have any error in the response.

Comment: Already checked that, the requests just 302 redirects...